# Write to TCP Stream of another program for which i read the packets

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp, stream

I managed to read the incoming und outgoing packets (as its done here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17031/A-Network-Sniffer-in-C) of another program for which i do not have the SourceCode.
Now I also want to write to that stream or add my own packets so that the server accepts them as valid tcp packets.

Is there a way to get that network stream or write raw packets as valid tcp packets to the server?

Detail:
I am reading the traffic of the program with its server here:

```
mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Unspecified);

mainSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, true);

IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList
.Where((addr) => addr.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
.Where((addr) => addr.GetAddressBytes()[0] != 127)
.First();

mainSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 0));

byte[] byTrue = new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
            byte[] byOut = new byte[4];

mainSocket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, byTrue, byOut);

byteData = new byte[4096];

mainSocket.BeginReceive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
```

In the OnReceive I parse the data into IPPackets and TCPPackets to analyze the Destintion IP and Port to determine my relevant packtets and stream.

Now I want to write packets to this stream either by getting the tcp stream as a NetworkStream or by sending specific packets to the servers IP:Port.

What I tried so far:

```
public static void DoSomething(string targetIP, int targetPort)
{
IPAddress targetIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(targetIP);
IPEndPoint target = new IPEndPoint(targetIPAddress, targetPort);

TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
tcpClient.Connect(target);
NetworkStream netStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

var packet = {0x6d, 0x4b, 0x4e, 0x09, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}

if (netStream.CanWrite)
{
     netStream.Write(packet, 0, packet.Length);
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("You cannot write data to this stream.");
      tcpClient.Close();
      netStream.Close();
      return;
}

}
```

or packetwise

```
mainSocket.Connect(target);
mainSocket.Send(packet);
```

I want to send the packet so it looks like it would have been sended within the existing network stream.
If its easier I am also glad about answers in c, c++/cpp, c#, java, js, autoit ...

Merci alot and have a nice weekend

**Edit:** I managed to write a send a tcp packet similiar to the packages of the other program. But according to Wireshark the Packages are marked as "out of order". Are such "out of order" packets usualy accepted and interpreted?
And what could I do to set the packets in the correct order?

This is what I do to send the packets:

```
ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

struct sockaddr_in clientService;
clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
clientService.sin_port = htons(port);

iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&clientService, szeof(clientService));

iResult = send(ConnectSocket, buf, 5, 0);
```

So as far as i understood from the comments of jdweng there is no way to grab the existing stream?
I imagine something like grabbing the pointer to the stream of the other program and cast it to a stream so my program can write to the same stream.
Is that or something like that possible?

**BUMP:** Anyone has an Idea of how to do this?

Comment: It would probably be easier to do in c++ than c#.  A TCP message is a byte array with an IP Header followed by a TCP Header and than the TCP data.  The max size is ~1500 bytes.  When you have more than 1500 bytes the message is broken into multiple datagrams.  See Wiki for the format of the headers : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4 and
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

Comment: @jdweng Thank you very much for the reply.
Can you give a short example of how the ip and tcp header can be created and packed to send as one packet?
Do I have to set a specific sequence number or something like this to the tcp header?

Comment: Used the c++ send method : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-send.  The IP header is normally handled in the Network card which adds the sequence number.  You just have to specify the protocol. and the data which is the TCP header and TCP data.

Comment: @jdweng I used the c++ send method as described in the new edit part of the description. It generated a tcp packet with the seemengly correct data. But the packet is marked as "out of order" according to wireshark.
Can these "out of order" packets be accepted or what can I do to set them in the order?

Comment: The IP header has a sequence number and the network card will reorder the sequence when receiving messages before sending up the execution stack to the application.  With TCP there is no guarantee during transmission that every packet takes the same route when a message is greater than 1500 bytes.  So make sure the sequence number is in the correct order.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the explanation. But my Data is only 3-9 bytes in length so I think they are not split into datagrams and there is no need for that splitting, isnt it?
And how can one make sure the sequence number is in the correct order in the c++ send Method?

Comment: You can't stop splitting. Yes the probability is small when you have only 3-9 bytes, but a lot of methods use timers and the timers will cause spitting occasionally.  Sending data is moved from you application down the execution stack to the network card using streams and the stream will keep the sequence correct.  Once data is placed on the ethernet/internet with a sequence number there is no guarantee packets will take same route so the order that data is receive is not in same order sent.  So network card uses IP sequence number to reorder data in same order sent.

Comment: @jdweng thanks again. So is it possible to send a packet via c++ send to the same stream, the other program is sending to?
If it is not I would like to ask how to simulate my packet as a packet from the other program. In wireshark I can see, that my packet has another destination port than the packets send by the programm. And the sequence number of my Packets start at 1. The Packets from the other program have a high sequence numer. Can I adjust these prarameters for the packets I send or even grab the existing stream in c?

Comment: I meant source port ... my packets do have another source port than the packets send by the program. maybe that is why my packets are not interpreted by the server.

Comment: You have a stream from the application to the socket (the IP header).  The socket class contains the Source IP, Destination IP, Port number, Protocol.  There are private properties like the sequence number (identification), and offset.   When you send you are only sending the data and not the header.  A listener can accept more than one client.  It only cares about the port number and doesn't care about the Source IP address.  So when you test you just send to a Port number and an IP.  If you want to send from same IP more than one connection than you need a new listener for each port.

Comment: A connection must have a unique combination of 3 properties 1) Source IP 2) Destination IP 3) Port number.  So you can't have two connections between a Source IP and Destination IP with same port number.  The listener should always using from end point IP.Any so when you test on same machine you do not get a conflict with the three properties above.  The IP.Any is virtual port than doesn't conflict with the IP address of the machine nor the loopback (127.0.0.1).